# Why is John the Ripper not showing any password? Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, passwords

when I enter this line in cmd: `john cracked.txt`
The answer is:

> Loaded 6 password hashes with no different salts (LM [DES 256/256
> AVX2])
>
> No password hashes left to crack (see FAQ)

And when I enter: `john --show cracked.txt`
The answer is:

> test::1002:AAD3B435B51404EEAAD3B435B51404EE:794921AEB4FDDE79E460831F1399EE2B
>
> 6 password hashes cracked, 0 left

The password of the user test isn't "1002" and it's assumed that you already have it and should show it but it's showing that the password is empty

Comment: Find the file `john.pot` and look inside.

Comment: There´s this inside, nothing more: $LM$aad3b435b51404ee: